# Regular expression to filter lines based on a word combination

Tags: regex, expression

I want to create a regular expression to filter lines based on a word combination.

In the following example I want to match any lines that have `wheel` and ignore any lines that have `steering` in them. In the example below there are lines with both. I want to skip the line with steeringWheel but select all the rest.

```
chrysler::plastic::steeringWheel

chrysler::chrome::L_rearWheelCentre

chrysler::chrome::R_rearWheelCentre
```

If I do the following

```
.*(Wheel|^steering).*
```

It would find lines including steeringWheel.

Comment: You seem to need `(?i)^(?!.*steering).*wheel.*`

Comment: It is getting a bit confusing if I need to add more patterns. Is there a cleaner way to say all wheels matches except those with steering?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Let say I want to say match wheel and tyre but exclude steering from those matches.

Comment: Use `(?i)^(?!.*steering).*(wheel|tyre).* `

Comment: Yes it works. You can add it is an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a negative lookahead anchored at the start:

```
(?i)^(?!.*steering).*(wheel|tyre).*
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yMJvv4/1).

The pattern matches:

- `(?i)` - make the pattern case insensitive
- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*steering)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `steering` substring after any 0+ chars
- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible up to the last occurrence of
- `(wheel|tyre)` - either `wheel` or `tyre`
- `.*`  - any 0+ chars up to the end of line.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work. It uses a negative lookbehind, assuming that the word steering will be immediately followed by the word 'wheel'.

```
.*(?<!steering)Wheel.*
```

Comment: This will still match `chrysler::plastic::steeringWheel::Wheel`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to write it all as one regex.  My understanding is regex doesn't truly support not matching words.  The negative look arounds are good, but it has to be right there next to it not just somewhere on the line.  What you are trying to do with ^ is for character classes like:

```
[^abc0-9] #not a character a,b,c,0..9
```

If possible something like this should work:

```
thelist = [
"chrysler::plastic::steeringWheel", 
"chrysler::chrome::L_rearWheelCentre",
"chrysler::chrome::R_rearWheelCentre"
]

theregex_wheel = re.compile("wheel", re.IGNORECASE)
theregex_steering = re.compile("steering", re.IGNORECASE)

for thestring in thelist:
    if re.search(theregex_wheel, thestring) and not re.search(theregex_steering, thestring):
        print ("yep, want this")
    else:
        print ("skip this guy")
```